# Pdf generation in arabic language is printing garbage values

Tags: pdf, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, componentone

I am using component one library to generate pdf document and save in phone storage. Here is my code to print just one line.

```
        public ViewStatementDetails()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;

        pdf = new C1PdfDocument(PaperKind.Letter);
        pdf.Clear();
    }

    private void Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadingProgress.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
        PDFTest_Loaded();
    }


    async void PDFTest_Loaded()
    {
        try
        {
            WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = await initializeImage();
            pdf = new C1PdfDocument(PaperKind.Letter);
            CreateDocumentText(pdf);

            StorageFile Assets = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Salik Statement.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

            PdfUtils.Save(pdf, Assets);
            LoadingProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Debugger.Break();
            LoadingProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

async void CreateDocumentText(C1PdfDocument pdf)
    {
        try
        {
            pdf.Landscape = false;

            // measure and show some text 
            var text = App.GetResource("RoadAndSafetyheading")
            var font = new Font("Segoe UI Light", 36, PdfFontStyle.Bold);

            var fmt = new StringFormat();
            fmt.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            // measure it
            var sz = pdf.MeasureString(text, font, 72 * 3, fmt);
            var rc = new Rect(0, 0, pdf.PageRectangle.Width, sz.Height);
            rc = PdfUtils.Offset(rc, 0, 0);

            // draw the text
            pdf.DrawString(text, font, Colors.Orange, rc, fmt);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

The above code is working perfect but my application supports two languages, English and Arabic. And when I am in arabic mode and generate same pdf it prints garbage values in pdf file. attaching image of printed characters.

[image]

Comment: same case happening to me.. looks like encoding issue.. any one created arabic or other language pdf before?

Answer (score 0):

Use of Arabic characters would require to use Unicode symbols and embed the Unicode font into PDF (as PDF format does not provide support for Unicode using its built-in fonts). If you are using ComponentOne then try to set .EmbedTrueTypeFonts = true (see details [here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1report/C1.C1Report.4~C1.C1Preview.Export.C1dExporterBase~EmbedTrueTypeFonts.html))

Comment: where I should add this?

Comment: is this property exist for winrt application ?

Comment: Seems like WinRT does not provide support for this property: http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/PDFWinRT/C1.Xaml.Pdf~C1.Xaml.Pdf.C1PdfDocument_members.html :(